# Selecting the right user testing method for mobile app

Tags: usability-testing, methodology, ab-testing, ux-methods

We have a mobile app for different platforms. And now we want to improve the UX and UI. Due to the security policy, we cannot install analytic tools. I'm thinking of options we have to measure our design improvements impact: One-on-one A/B testing with 20 users per design to measure speed, number of errors, satisfaction rate etc. That's about 40 user tests per design update, which seems to be not realistically for our company. Any more variants or thoughts? Once in a few months we have 1 negative feedback about the design like "I don't like it" and some more feedback like "I like it".

Comment: By _one-on-one_ I guess you’re referring to moderated usability tests? What about unmoderated ones? There are platforms out there that allow to automate the recruiting, testing and analytics. You can track task metrics, and have the tester’s voice to analyse the WHY behind a fail.

Comment: Norman-Nielsen always talks about the fact that with ca. 7 participants, you'll see all important issues. So you might not need the full 20. Especially if you company is sceptical or short on budget (for this topic), starting with a small study might be a good way to demonstrate the usefulness of such feedback. If you fix all issues you find with 7 participants, your product will be much better compared to if you hadn't done any tests :-)

Answer (score 1):

we use SUS questionnaire for our usability test in a company. It contains 10 questions which contains negative as well as positive feedback. The more information might be helpful here: https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html.

Comment: How do you engage your users to fill in the questionnaire? The proposeds variant are not short, so the person probably should be very motivated.

Comment: We make in-house usability test so that many of the co-workers are inthusastics. The process takes place in five stages: 1. we ask them to tell about something themsleves. 2. Later on we introduce the product which we are going to test. 2. Theere are certain tasks which should be completed with users.

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad you can't place Google Analytics, or similar traffic analysis tool, on your mobile app. Usage is always your best indicator of utility.

Many of the video testing platforms now include space for opinion polls or SUS scores. These can provide a quantitative context for what is a very qualitative way of assessing usability.

The video recordings, using "think-aloud" narration, are an excellent way to identify errors in mobile UI. If you haven't tried them out yet, demo [UserTesting](https://www.usertesting.com/), [Userlytics](https://www.userlytics.com/) or [UserZoom](https://www.userzoom.com/) for video testing your mobile app.

Comment: Actually you can use Google Analytics for your mobile app: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile

Comment: OT: I have Google Analytics turned off on all my browsers. What doesn't work without it, will be used only in very exceptional circumstances. I consider the dissemination of my usage data to Google to be a very bad (albeit hidden) user experience - some day, it'll come back in the form of advertising or manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Lookback or UserTesting can be helpful you. Conduct unmoderated remote usability tests. You can recruit participants who match your target audience. Do observe their interactions with the app while recording their screens and voices. 5-10 participants per design can definitely provide valuable insights.